# Семантический HTML-тег для отступа стихотворения?

Tags: html, семантика

Во всяких печатных книжках стихотворения внутри прозы зачастую выделяют отступом от левого края, примерно так:

```
Проходя мимо камина, бросила взгляд на стишок в рамке.

        Десять негритят решили пообедать,
        Один внезапно подавился – их осталось девять.

«Какой ужас – прямо как у нас сегодня вечером…» – подумала девушка.
```

Существует ли какой-нибудь HTML-тег, подходящий по семантике в подобных случаях? Самое близкое, что я знаю, это `blockquote`, но стихотворения — не всегда цитаты.

Уточнение: подразумевается, что само стихотворение не имеет в себе таких пробелов, отступ может устанавливаться через CSS. Или не устанавливаться, это уж как дизайнер захочет) Интересует чисто семантика.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734564/how-to-semantically-tag-poem-text

Answer (score 0):

> The pre element represents a block of preformatted text, in which structure is represented by typographic conventions rather than by elements.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element

Элемент `<pre>` отображает блок отформатированного текста, структура которого определяется не элементами, а типографическими соглашениями.

По-умолчанию отображается моноширинным шрифтом.

Comment: Бррррррррррр...

Comment: @Qwertiy что-то не так?

Comment: По-моему, вовсем не тот тег.

Comment: @Qwertiy спецификация говорит об обратном.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется что не тот, само стихотворение пробелов не содержит, отступ это лишь вариант выделения, который может быть и padding'ом в CSS например

Comment: ...хотя информация по ссылке Cheg намекает, что всё не так просто

Comment: @andreymal автор не уточнил, каким образом у него задаются отступы (или ему необходимо, чтобы они задавались). Он попросил предоставить наиболее семантичный тег для данного случая - мой ответ в полной мере отвечает его требованиям.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так:

```html
<blockquote style="padding-left: 2vw">
Десять негритят решили пообедать,
Один внезапно подавился – их осталось девять.
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Как я уже написал в тексте вопроса, «стихотворения — не всегда цитаты»